# Sending email from browser mailgun

Tags: javascript, postman, mailgun

I want to send a simple email from the browser using `mailgun`. I send a working email from `postman` and with the download code function I managed to get the javascript code which is:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("from", "Mailgun Sandbox <postmaster@sandbox1985406854ad9e8b8dfe094531fa41e8.mailgun.org>");
data.append("to", "Example <example@gmail.com>");
data.append("subject", "Hello from Mailgun");
data.append("text", "Congratulations Example, you just sent an email with Mailgun!  You are truly awesome!");

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("POST", "https://api:key-75a05cfds8c66bd1y4c3e854305438e5@api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox1985406854ad9e8b8dfe094531fa41e8.mailgun.org/messages");
xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
xhr.setRequestHeader("postman-token", "0a3ad9d5-22b5-6308-d6e7-59f66360fa26");

xhr.send(data);
```

But when I execute this code from my browser (`firefox`) it does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Changing the url from

`https://api:key-75a05cfds8c66bd1y4c3e854305438e5@api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox1985406854ad9e8b8dfe094531fa41e8.mailgun.org/messages`

to

`https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox1985406854ad9e8b8dfe094531fa41e8.mailgun.org/messages`

seems to execute, is the `api:key-xx` part invalid?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm looking to do the same thing as you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this. This is not an appropriate use of the Mailgun API.

By delivering this Javascript to a browser, you are giving them access to your Mailgun API key. This API key is not limited in any way whatsoever -- a malicious client could misuse the key to send an unlimited number of messages to any recipient they want, potentially racking up large bills and/or getting your account blocked for spam.

Use the Mailgun API on the server side. If you need to send messages via Javascript, create an endpoint in your application which calls the Mailgun API with appropriate restrictions in place.

Comment: Yes I know it's terrible, but at this point I'm more curious as to why it isn't working instead of getting it to work. I've created a backend server already which sends the email.

Comment: I'm curious how to get this to work in the browser as well. My implementation would do it as a Chrome Extension. At that point the only person with access to the API key is the end user who would provide their own key.